# Is it possible to make a discord js website and how?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is it possible to make a website that connects to my discord js bot and shows user count?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Either save the number of user count in a database or file or whatever and just display that number on the website.

Comment: Could I use a json file?

Comment: How would I show the json on the website

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're using.. If you're using PHP you read the file and place it on the right spot. If you're using Express you read the file and place it on the right spot. If you're using ASP.NET you read the file and place it on the right spot.

Comment: I'm using express and html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found you can use

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/6b3bfdd7dede049ba592e94ef1b1acc40a5e37fe/docs/topics/web.md

and

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/tree/webpack

to make a website using discord.js but the connection can be controlled in the chrome console like a full eval

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible but you are going to have to host it yourself. Typically with these websites, you will have a profile page for all of the servers with your bot in it. You can then modify it on the website and it will store that data in some form that will affect how your bot acts. However, it does look like it requires a lot of research and experience in a couple different languages. I say that anyone can do it with enough time, so I encourage you to try it out. You might learn a thing or two!

Wishing you good luck

-Zaedus